# create dashed continuous lines instead of putting the words to the next line in word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I create line endings like this automatically in word:

[image: dashed line endings]

Note: There is an option to justify the text in word but that does not create the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable auto-hyphenation in one of two ways (depending on your version of Word).

Newer versions require you to click on the "Layout" tab of the ribbon... and then click on "Hyphenation" and click "Automatic".

Older versions you would click on the "Tools" menu, then "Language", and finally "Hyphenation".  From there, you can check the box that says "Automatically hyphenate document".

Comment: `CTRL`+`-` adds a possible hyphen in a word, if the automation doesn't.